# What is the difference in using CountAsync or AsyncEnumerable CountAwaitAsync?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

What is the difference in using CountAsync or AsyncEnumerable CountAwaitAsync?

In AsyncEnumerable.cs there is:

```
public static ValueTask<int> CountAwaitAsync<[Nullable(2)] TSource>(
      [Nullable(1)] this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source,
      [Nullable(new byte[] {1, 1, 0})] Func<TSource, ValueTask<bool>> predicate,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));
```

1. Why is there an await in the name?
2. Why can it only be called with a predicate?

Both make no sense to me, but I am sure there is a sense. I don't get it.

Comment: Food for thought, if you're going to run CountAsync and then check to see if the Count is greater than 0, then you should instead use .AnyAsync, as this is much, much faster in dotnet core!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CountAsync` is for the case when predicate (`Func<TSource, bool>`) is synchronous.

`CountAwaitAsync` is for the case when predicate is an asynchronous lambda. Hence its signature is `Func<TSource, ValueTask<bool>>`. With default predicate `a => true` there is no need in asynchronousity, so I think that's why there is no default predicate here.

Update: as per @Sir Rufo, Count**Await**Async waits for predicate so there is Await in its name.

Comment: ... and each ValueTask from predicate will be awaited by Count**Await**Async

Comment: isn’t the default predicate `a => true`?

Comment: @SirRufo , thanks for the comments, I've edited my answer

Comment: ok that makes sense. sadly there is no such xml comment in the decompiled sources.